# Need instructions for adding a Facebook Like button without using Open Graph meta tags

Tags: facebook-like

I can't find the specific instructions for adding a Like button to a page without including open graph tags on that page. The page in question is a third-party registration site, and we don't have access to the page header to add meta tags. I believe that there was an older version that didn't use the Open Graph (before it existed?)

Any help or advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a like button without Open Graph tags, however you can not set the title, description and image.

The [old version of share buttons is deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) and will be unsupported soon.

Comment: 'Old version of the like button is deprecated'? Where did you see that? (the rest of your answer is correct, though)